# How Do I Replace a disk in a ZFS Root Pool Setup?

Tags: server, zfs

I setup a ZFS root pool via the following steps in the tutorial, and don't know how to replace the disk correctly. Can you assist me with the steps?

https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2020.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html#overview

Answer (score 0):

Here it is horribly formatted, but works like a charm for me:

In Order To Replace A Boot Disk With The Root ZFS System, you need to zap the new disk

NEWDISK=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ZA3840NM10001_HKT01PCD
sudo wipefs -af $NEWDISK
sudo sgdisk --zap-all $NEWDISK
sudo sgdisk -n1:1M:+512M -t1:EF00 $NEWDISK
sudo sgdisk -n2:0:+1024M -t2:FD00 $NEWDISK
sudo sgdisk -n3:0:+2G -t3:BE00 $NEWDISK
sudo sgdisk -n4:0:0 -t4:BF00 $NEWDISK

#Create the EFI partition 1
#Reset all your variables in this new sudo -i
sudo -i
DISK1=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST4000DM000-1F2168_Z3074N81
DISK2=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ZA3840NM10001_HKT01SPD
DISK3=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ZA3840NM10001_HKT01P3S
DISK4=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ZA3840NM10001_HKT01PCD

mkdosfs -F 32 -s 1 -n EFI ${DISK1}-part1
mkdir /boot/efi
echo UUID=$(blkid -s UUID -o value ${DISK1}-part1) 
/boot/efi vfat umask=0022,fmask=0022,dmask=0022 0 1 > /etc/fstab
mount /boot/efi

mkdosfs -F 32 -s 1 -n EFI ${DISK2}-part1
mkdir /boot/efi2
echo UUID=$(blkid -s UUID -o value ${DISK2}-part1) 
/boot/efi2 vfat umask=0022,fmask=0022,dmask=0022 0 1 >> /etc/fstab
mount /boot/efi2

mkdosfs -F 32 -s 1 -n EFI ${DISK3}-part1
mkdir /boot/efi3
echo UUID=$(blkid -s UUID -o value ${DISK3}-part1) 
/boot/efi3 vfat umask=0022,fmask=0022,dmask=0022 0 1 >> /etc/fstab
mount /boot/efi3

mkdosfs -F 32 -s 1 -n EFI ${DISK4}-part1
mkdir /boot/efi4
echo UUID=$(blkid -s UUID -o value ${DISK4}-part1) 
/boot/efi4 vfat umask=0022,fmask=0022,dmask=0022 0 1 >> /etc/fstab
mount /boot/efi4

#Next Re-Create the Swap Partition 2
#make sure you are still in root mode!!!

## Stop the array in case it is running:

mdadm -Esv
mdadm  --stop /dev/md*
mdadm --misc --scan --detail /dev/md0
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --metadata=1.2 --level=raid5 
--raid-devices=4 ${DISK1}-part2 ${DISK3}-part2 
${DISK2}-part2 ${DISK4}-part2

mkswap -f /dev/md0
echo UUID=$(blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/md0) 
none swap discard 0 0 >> /etc/fstab
swapon -a

#Next get part 3 and 4 setup.

## make sure you exit root here

```
exit
```

Do a sudo zpool status to get the GUID of the record: 6491063046595957463

Then, do a sudo zpool replace [pool_name] [guid] $DISK2-part[0-9]
Ex:

sudo zpool replace rpool 13395510599896975344 $NEWDISK-part4
sudo zpool replace bpool 14748746258678915344 $NEWDISK-part3